# List of Linux programs which are not in macOS

Tags: unix

I know the following programs are in Linux but not in macOS.

Are there more?
Where can I find the list?

Please ignore BSD counterparts.

```
tree
watch
wget
wdiff
gdb
autoconf
```

Comment: There is no "list", nor are those particularly "Linux" programs.  If you want those, install those.  If you want to do the job of those, why would you ignore the BSD equivalents?  Many people find lldb quite sufficient, for example.

Comment: If you want to ignore BSD counterparts then the list is basically all GNU/Linux programs except bash and rsync which are many versions behind current ones. macOS is based on BSD not GNU and does not include GNU code. Also note gdb is not on all GNU/Linux systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists millions and millions of programs out there in the world. Some work on Linux, some work on macOS - some work both places.

No-one has or could have a complete list of such programs.

The list you have of programs not available on macOS does not seem to be entirely correct either. A `watch` program is indeed included in the default macOS installation. The rest can easily be installed - for example if you install HomeBrew, you can install the `tree`, `wget`, `wdiff`, `gdb` and `autoconf` commands by running:

```
brew install tree wget wdiff gdb autoconf
```

Note that lots of programs, particularly old ones, exist in multiple versions with the same name. For example Linux draws a lot of programs in from the GNU project, where macOS draws some programs in from the BSD world. So you might have programs with the same name and intended primary functionality on both Linux and macOS, but underlying are really two different programs. In many cases, you can just install the GNU version instead if you dislike the BSD version.

Comment: `watch` is not in El Capitan, High Sierra, or Catalina. These are the ones I know.

Comment: @lhf Just install HomeBrew and run "brew install watch" - then you have watch on those systems.

Comment: I was commenting on your claim: "A watch program is indeed included in the default macOS installation."